# High School learning address

Tags: phrase-requests

I must insert in my curriculum my high school studies. Well, nothing bad with this,unless for a small thing.

I attended High School in Italy, My school was not a technical school but what we call a "Liceo", an institution made for those one who wants to continue studying after graduation.

In Italy every school has many learning courses, let's call them in this way.
For example, in Italy, in my school, I could choose among this possibilities:

- A normal course
- A 2 years intensive math and physics + 3 years philosophy and physics course
- A special course with no Latin language to be studied

I am calling them courses but in Italian they are called "Indirizzi di studio", verbatim they are "Study addresses".

How would you refer to them in English?

Comment: I would think just courses is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a discussion on Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=435391), you could say **program of study** (or "programme of study" if you're writing for a British audience).

Comment: Really, Antony? Do you mean that in terms of university? I haven't heard anyone in the UK, say that in the context of school courses.

Answer (score 1):

A **course** is one single subject for one year or period, for example, a course in Greek Philosophy or Single Variable Calculus. "How many courses are you taking this semester?" "Only four, but my class in German is really intense." 'Course' and 'class' are synonyms (but not always interchangeable.

A sequence of courses is a **curriculum** (pl. curricula) or, less formally, a **track** for a particular sequence within a curriculum.  If you are focussing on letters and languages, you would be following a general humanities curriculum. If you are taking general sciences over a few years plus some advanced math concepts, you might be on an advanced mathematics track.

Answer (score 0):

The word *courses* would be fine. In the UK, at least.